# Essential clarifications on application of pigeonhole principle

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, discrete-geometry, arithmetic-progression

In here Lemma $4$ using pigeonhole says:

For $T_1,\dots,T_s\in\Bbb R$ with $1\leq T_1,\dots,T_s<p$ and $\prod_{i=1}^sT_i > p^{s−1}$ and any integers $a_1,\dots,a_s$ there is an integer $t$ coprime to $p$ such that
$$\min_{
k\in\Bbb Z}|ta_i − kp| \ll T_i,\quad\quad i = 1,\dots,s$$ holds.

**First of all is this even true?** Are we interpreting $(a_1,\dots,a_s)$ as a straight line in $\Bbb Z^s$?

Every integer $s$-tuple $a_1,\dots,a_s$ has $p$ mappings by $t(a_1,\dots,a_s)\bmod p$ where $t$ ranges from $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. Unless we assume some uniformity in mapping I so not see how there is a $t$ such that $t(a_1,\dots,a_s)\bmod p\in[-T_1,T_1]\times[-T_2,T_2]\times\dots\times[-T_s,T_s]$ holds? If we had $p^s-p^{s-1}$ different choices of $t$ then pigeonhole works. Since $p\ll p^s-p^{s-1}$ is this some kind of randomized pigeonhole or just an argument assuming $(a_1,\dots,a_s)$ as a straight line in $\Bbb Z^s$?

---

Assuming we have the needed result as in Lemma $4$ then my main query is following (which satisfy pigeonhole):

**(1)** Can we replace real numbers $T_1,\dots,T_s$ by intervals $I_1=[T_0,T_1]$, $I_2=[T_1,T_2]$,$\dots$, $I_s=[T_{s-1},T_s]$ and now have following lemma?

For any real intervals $I_1=[T_0,T_1]$, $I_2=[T_1,T_2]$,$\dots$, $I_s=[T_{s-1},T_s]$ with $$0\leq T_0,T_1,\dots,T_s<p,\quad1\leq|I_1|,\dots,|I_s|<p,\quad\prod_{i=1}^s|I_i|> p^{s−1}$$
and any integers $a_1,\dots,a_s$ there is an integer $t$ coprime to $p$ such that
$$\min_{
k\in\Bbb Z}|ta_i − kp|\in I_i,\quad\quad i = 1,\dots,s$$ holds.

My second query is following (which also allows pigeonhole combinatorics to work):

**(2)** Why cannot I replace $\min_{
k\in\Bbb Z}|ta_i − kp|$ by $\min_{\substack{
k\in\Bbb Z\\ta_i-kp\geq0}}(ta_i − kp)$ or $\min_{\substack{
k\in\Bbb Z\\ta_i-kp\leq0}}(-ta_i + kp)$?

Comment: I think you meant $||a_i t||$ as in the linked paper.

Comment: Also, $a$ should be replaced by $a_i$, so that $\min_{t\in \mathbb{Z}} |a_i - tp|$

Comment: @i707107 thank you corrected. Is **(1)** possible and in **(2)** can we replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we prove the Lemma 4. Considering the linked paper (that was in the previous version of this question), $p$ must be a prime number.

We apply the pigeon-hole principle in the following way:

Take $T_i'$ to satisfy $T_i\leq T_i'$ and $p/T_i' \in \mathbb{N}$. This is possible without changing $T_i$ too much (still satisfying $T_i\asymp T_i'$). Subdivide the interval $[0,p]$ into $p/T_i'$ equal pieces. Considering the subdivision in each component $i$, we have a subdivision of the $s$-cube $[0,p]^s$ into $N=\prod (p/T_i')$ equal  boxes. Now given $\prod T_i > p^{s-1}$ gives $\prod T_i'> p^{s-1}$. Then the number of boxes inside $[0,p]^s$ with the subdivision is $<p$. Consider the following for $t=0, 1, \ldots, p-1$:
$$
(a_1, \ldots, a_s) t \ \mathrm{mod} \ p,
$$
**Here comes the key argument in the pigeon-hole principle.**

Since the number of boxes $N$ is $<p$, there must be two distinct $t_0, t_1 \in \{0, 1, \ldots p-1\}$ such that $(a_1, \ldots, a_s) t_0 \ \mathrm{mod} \ p$ and $(a_1, \ldots , a_s) t_1 \ \mathrm{mod} \ p$ lie in the same box. Take $t=|t_0-t_1|$, then $0<t<p$ so that $(t,p)=1$ and for each $i=1, \ldots, s$, 
$$
a_i|t_0-t_1| \ \mathrm{mod} \ p \textrm{ is in the interval } [-T_i' , T_i'].
$$

Now for your questions, this argument does not guarantee the specific location of $(a_1, \ldots , a_s) t$ modulo $p$ other than just a box around the origin. So, in your setting of specified box, it might not be possible. With a little care, you can make a counterexample (e. g. with $s=2$, $p=37$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $|I_1|=37/6$, $|I_2|=37/6$ where $|I|$ is the length of the interval $I$).

For using $\min_{k\in \mathbb{Z} \\ a_i t - kp\geq 0} (a_i t - kp)$ or $\min{k\in\mathbb{Z}\\ a_i t - kp \leq 0 } (-a_i t + kp)$, we also see that the calculation modulo $p$ does not guarantee the specific sign of $a_i t - kp$. So, it is not possible to replace by those.

Comment: $s=2$, $p=37$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $T_1=37/6$, $T_2=37/6$ is not a valid example. I assume you choose $T_0=0$. Then intervals are $I_1=[0,37/6]$ and $I_2=[37/6,37/6]$ and so $|I_1|=37/6$ and $|I_2|=0$. So we have two violations $|I_2|=0<1$ and $|I_1||I_2|=0<37^{s-1}=37$.

Comment: If you are saying $I_1'=[0,37/6]$ and $I_2'=[37/6,74/6]$ then we have $4(a_1,a_2)\bmod 37\equiv 4(1,2)\bmod 37\equiv(4,8)\in[0,37/6]\times[37/6,74/6]$.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that length of $I_1$ and $I_2$ are $37/6$.

Comment: In my example $|I_1'|=|I_2'|=37/6$.

Comment: If the intervals are $I_1= [0, 37/6]$, $I_2 = [37 \cdot \frac 56, 37]$, then $I_1\times I_2$ does not contain any point of $(1,2)t$ mod $37$.

Comment: may I ask a query? If $\prod_{i=1}^s T_i>p^{s-1}(\log p)^{2+\epsilon}$ then in the lemma $4$ can we expect at least one such $t$ which is prime (that is at least for one $|t_1-t_0|$ with $0<|t_1-t_0|<p$ is prime).

Comment: Because we have less number of boxes, we expect many points inside a box. However, I am not sure that we may make $|t_1-t_0|$ prime.

Comment: Does $p$ have to be prime or can it even be of form $2^t$?

Comment: I remember that $p$ has to be prime. This was given in the paper OP posted in the first place. It is not linked in the question now. See the edit history.

Comment: How about just the case $p=2^t$ and $s=2$ with odd $a_1,a_2$ satisfying $a_1<a_2<2a_1$ and $gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$?

Comment: If you see [the paper](http://www.anazumalacarregui.org/publications/EC_ConcentrationPoints.pdf), we see that the existence of $0<t<p$ with $(t,p)=1$ requires $p$ to be prime. If $p=2^t$, such $t$ with $0<t<p$ might not satisfy $(t,p)=1$.

Comment: sorry the $t$ in $p=2^t$ is different from $t$ in $0<t<p$. I should have said $p=2^{u}$. Hope that clarifies

Comment: Still, the problem remains. It might happen that $0<t<p$ with even $t$ does not satisfy $(t,p)=1$.

Comment: I dont get it all I seek is whether there is odd $t$ such that given odd coprime $a_1<a_2<2a_1$ we have $t(a_1,a_2)\bmod 2^u$ in $[-T_1,T_1]\times [-T_2,T_2]$ where $T_1T_2>2^{u+2}>T_1,T_2$ holds. i do not want even t. Your argument of partitioning $[0,2^u]\times[0,2^u]$ still works. Number of boxes is $\frac{2^u}{T_1}\frac{2^u}{T_2}<2^{u-2}$ there must be an odd $t_1$ and an even $t_2$ that lie in same box. right? and $|t_1-t_2|=t$ is odd which means $(t,2^u)=1$. Where is the issue?

Comment: I am not sure if we can guarantee that $t_1$ is odd and $t_2$ is even.

Comment: There are $2^{u-1}$ odd $t$ and $2^{u-1}$ even $t$. So if there are at most $2^{u-2}$ boxes and if we fix odd $t_1$ in a box then there is an even $t_2$ which falls in same box. right?

Comment: Can we replace one $T_i$ by an interval $[(s+1)T_i,(s+3)T_i]$ and leave rest as $[-T_j,T_j]$?

Comment: If number boxes $N<p$ then there are two $t$s in same box and their difference brings you around origin. Suppose $N=p^{1-\epsilon}$ then can we expect $p^{\epsilon}$ different $t$s which bring you close to origin? Can we expect the vectors inside the boxes to be linearly independent at least at two different primes $p$ and $q$?

Comment: linearly independent assuming $p^\epsilon\leq s$ holds?

Comment: @i707107 If we look for two different $t$'s then what replaces $p^{s-1}$ in $\prod_{i=1}^sT_i>p^{s-1}$?

Comment: @i707107 Ok I see $>2p$ suffices. If we seek $r$ distinct $t$'s then my guess would be $>pr$ suffices.