# Approximately satisfying simultaneous vector linear diophantine equations?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, probabilistic-number-theory

Pick three $a,b,c$ vectors in $\mathbb Z^n$ uniformly with $\max(\|a\|_\infty,\|b\|_\infty)<T$ and $\|c\|_\infty<T^2$ and an $\epsilon>0$.

> Assume $a$ and $b$ are coordinatewise coprime (that is every $a_i$ and $b_i$ are coprime at every $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$). Then do we always have such $A$ and $B$ of absolute value $O(T)$ at general $n$ such that $\|Aa+Bb-c\|_\infty<T^{2(n-1)/n+\epsilon}$ at large enough $n$?

This is the intuition.

Essentially there are $T^2$ choices for $A,B$ and there are $T^{\frac{(2n−2)}n+\epsilon}$ choices for every coordinate of $Aa+Bb-c$ and since there are $n$ coordinates we have $T^2T^{{2n−2}+n\epsilon}=T^{2n+n\epsilon}$ choices. However typically $Aa+Bb-c$ is of size $T^2$ and so typically there are $T^{2n}$ choices. If $\epsilon>0$ then the heuristic that $$\frac{\{\mbox{number of choices for A,B}\}\times\{\mbox{number of vectors with }\infty\mbox{ norm GAP < }T^{\frac{2(n-1)}n+\epsilon}\}}{\mbox{number of length n vectors with coordinates of size }T^2}$$
$$\asymp\frac{T^2T^{(\frac{2(n-1)}n+\epsilon)n}}{T^{2n}}=T^{n\epsilon}$$ holds which is at least $1$ if $\epsilon>0$ implies the $\infty$ norm bound looks plausible.

> Also the original problem was what is the probability that the bound holds for uniformly random vectors $a,b,c$ in $\mathbb Z^n$ with $\max(\|a\|_\infty,\|b\|_\infty)<T$ and $\|c\|_\infty<T^2$ and an $\epsilon>0$?

At $n=1$ we get $\frac6{\pi^2}$.

**Update** The original writeup had a miscalculation. I missed a $2$ in exponent (that made the problem silly which some poster answered) and a related $T^2$ part (it was very clear from the denominator that the heuristic assumed a $T^2$ part on $c$ and I had not written it down in post) and it became WWIII and the accepted answer was for that original problem.

Comment: What's the motivation for the $(n-1)/n$ in the exponent?

Comment: My answer shows that this question is fundamentally misguided when $n \ge 3$. Why would you vote it down and then edit your question without taking it into account? You can't just vote away the truth you know.

Comment: @Turbo Why does your comment say that $Aa+Bb\in {\mathbb Z}$, while on line 1 of the current version of your question (version 5) you say $a,b,c\in {\mathbb Z}^n$? You seem to be motivated by https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263751/essential-clarifications-on-application-of-pigeonhole-principle so perhaps you should edit your question to explain the connection

Comment: @Turbo How about apologising to the user "A million tiny pieces", or acknowledging some of his or her remarks?

Comment: 1. OP gets an answer from new user which gives answer to question  2. OP abuses new user and claims answer is "incoherent" 3. New user gets upset, but OP relents and accepts answer. 4. New user goes away. 5. OP retracts acceptance and deletes all comments and acknowledgements as suggested by @YemonChoi. OP truly represents mathoverflow at its classiest!

Comment: @PoundSterling why is any communication dealing with my misunderstanding and his clarification abuse?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Correct exponent is I think $(2n-1)/n$ likely provable with pigeonhole.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Do you think $2(n-1)/n+\epsilon$ exponent could be provable? Essentially there are $T^2$ choices for $A$ and $B$ and if $(2n-2)/n$ is right exponent then there are $T^{(2n-2)/n+\epsilon}$ choices for every coordinate of $Aa+Bb$ and since there are $n$ coordinates we have $T^2T^{2n-2+n\epsilon}=T^{2n+n\epsilon}$ choices. However typically $Aa+Bb$ is of size $T^2$ and so typically there are $T^{2n}$ choices. If $\epsilon>0$ we have that $T^{2(n-1)/n}$ is right bound. Is there a way to convert the heuristic to a proof?

Comment: I think the heuristic may not reflect reality.

Comment: @PoundSterling How come you censor the fact that OP had infact suggested to delete everything and forget and infact he first deleted his comments and suggested.

Comment: I have had similar issues in the past. The post represents a moving target, discussions which might document a proper evolution to a good question are elided, answers which shed light on issues are deleted along with the question, a revised question which might (or might not) be headed in a good direction arises, and (on my part) a general air of frustration arises.  I have (with some small regret) adopted a policy of non involvement with such posts, as this behaviour seems to disregard the efforts I put into the question. I recommend such a policy here. This is too serious for a signature.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman An answer has already been accepted. I made the correction typo on a $2$ that resulted somehow from a $T^2$ that I miscalculated. Everything else is morally the same and I can say the answer accepted was for that part.

Comment: Yes, one has been accepted. So what? I still see comments and behaviour that suggests things are unstable.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman What do you want me to do? These comments are censored comments while in fact the poster told to delete and he deleted first. Regarding the validity of the problem it has been corrected with *update* where exactly I went wrong. Do you want me to do something else? If I dont accept the moderators will cast a taboo mail stating I am not accepting original answers. What do you want me to do? I also corected my original interpretation of the posters answer reasoning in favor of my mistaken 2. Then I looked again and corrected before that someone posted a comment and cast  ill omen.

Comment: I did not see the entire comment exchange but I did see a comment where you accused "a million tiny pieces" of being incoherent and you seem to have acknowledged voting the answer down. Since that answer was apparently correct without any edits required, one might hazard a guess that the reason for those comments being deleted was a million tiny pieces being generous to you not looking like a fool.

Comment: Given that all the subsequence versions have had problems it seems less like a "typo" and more that that after several bites at the apple there is nothing here. I would recommend that other users follow @GerhardPaseman's advice since I don't see what anyone has to gain from futher interaction on this question.

Comment: I have nothing to gain as well. You can do what you may. I already told my part. If users decides to respect a guy who first posts censored version and gets back to first ground they can decide on the worth of his Gold Silver comments.

Comment: He does not even acknowledge the difference between a typo $2$ and a mistaken $2$ (which I have clearly acknowledged as a mistake). I will comment no further on this.

Comment: What I really want is certain portions of the past not to have happened. I don't expect you to change the past. You can change your behaviour on this forum. If you want my renewed involvement in your questions, I am willing to try on your next question provided we agree that both of us follow certain rules on the handling of this next question.  I will not detail the rules now.  I will say that the intent of the rules is to acknowledge and preserve efforts toward changing the question for the better.

Comment: Okay, Turbo, I have read through the exchanges including the deleted comments. Gerhard and others were quite right. Moving forward: if you post a question and an answer reveals that there was a problem with the question, then let me suggest that the proper course of action is to admit openly that the answer was quite right, the question had a mistake, *thank* the user for pointing it out, use the strikethrough command so as not to cover up what happened, and *then* amend the question. People who are trying to be helpful deserve a gracious response and acknowledgment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even allowing $A$ and $B$ to be *real* numbers, the vectors $A a + B b$ will all lie in some fixed plane $P$. But then, if $n \ge 3$, for all but $\epsilon$ of the possible values of $c$ one will have

$$\| A a +  B b - c \|_{\infty} \gg T$$

where the constant depends only on $\epsilon$. So for $n \ge 3$ the probability will be zero even for this easier problem. Since in the comments you admit you just made up the exponent, there is not much motivation to think about precise asymptotics.

Comment: I do not think the answer is perfect. Expected L infinity distance between plane and hypercube is not unparametrizable and because of all the hullabullooo going on here I accept this being wary of the moderator taboo.

Comment: I don't know what "moderator taboo" signifies, but FWIW, one thing we've noticed is the huge number of self-deleted posts coming from this and allied accounts, which (cumulatively speaking) is tantamount to self-vandalism, and is frustrating to users who are trying to interact.

Comment: @ToddTrimble are you referring to the account behind this answer, or the account of the OP?

Comment: @YemonChoi I meant Turbo.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$ the probability that such $A$, $B$ exist is at least
$$\frac6{\pi^2}\left(1+\frac18\right)=68\%$$
since it can happen at least in the following two disjoint ways:

- $a$ and $b$ coprime
- $a$, $b$, $c$ are all even, and $a/2$, $b/2$ are coprime

Answer (score 0):

If $n = 1$, then (as $(a,b)=1$) there exist $A$ and $B$ such that $Aa+Bb-c = 0$, so $\|Aa+Bb-c\|_{\infty} = 0$.

If $n > 1$,take $A=B=0$ and then $\|Aa+Bb-c\|_{\infty} = \|c\|_{\infty} <  T$, which beats the suggested bound by a considerable margin.

Comment: Thanks corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This version (version 4 I think?) seems to have the exactly the same problem as solved by a previous answer. For a given $a$ and $b$ the vectors $Aa+Bb$ will still lie in a plane $P$, and so now for all but $\epsilon$ values of $c$ it will be the case that $\|Aa+Bb-c\| \gg T^2$ for some implicit constant depending on $\epsilon$.

"turbo" seems confused. As he says in the comments "If you dont want to answer just go away." An ironic response to someone who has now answered his question twice. I will follow his advice.

Comment: Ok. ,,, but we are looking at $\infty$ norm gap between best bounded plane and a point in box. Is it that easy? In fact $A=B=0$ (as in your previous answer) gives $O(T^2)$.

Comment: may be some other user141920's answer.

Comment: Yes it is easy --- after scaling, it is the same as saying that a vector with $\|x\|_{\infty} < 1$ is some at least some constant distance away from most planes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but $A=B=0$ gives $O(T^2)$ which is $\not\gg T^2$.

Comment: Do you know what the expression $\gg$ usually means in number theory? The expression $\gg T^2$ means bigger than $\delta T^2$ for an implicit constant $\delta$. As $c$ ranges over all $\|c\| \le T^2$ then $\|c\| \gg T^2$ for all but $\epsilon$ values of $c$.

Comment: Ah I see ok so you think it is impossible? Note infinity norm between two points in $[-T^2,T^2]^n$ box is bound by $2T^2$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but the point of my answer is that for all but $\epsilon$ choices of the parameter $\|aA+bB-c\| > \delta T^2$ so the probability is zero.

Comment: I dont follow your $\delta$ unless you make it explicit. For all $a,b$ and $c$ with said bounds we can take $A=B=0$ to get $\|Aa+Bb-c\|_\infty\leq T^2$. I am asking for a slight improvement. Will it be possible?

Comment: Also note even if the bound is $0.9999999T^2$ I think that may be enough for me.

Comment: Your bound is $T^{2(n-1)/n + \epsilon}$ ($=o(T^2)$ for $n \ge 3$)  --- are you seriously changing the question AGAIN to be a constant times $T^2$?

Comment: No I am not... did I change? All I state is even that is sufficient for me. Dont read beyong the lines. If you want to bring up a point go up with the other folks. If you dont want to answer just go away. I am not begging for your answer either and you are not solving GRH nor are you catching Al capone.